# ¿Como puedo codificar una consulta a MySQL a UTF-8?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

Bendo con un problema que aqueja.

Todos los registros que inserto a mi base de datos se guardan con caracteres de este tipo (Ã³). Este es una (ó). Mi problema es que estoy usando una función para que lo codifique como UTF-8 a la hora de consultar la información pero no me llega procesado.
El código que uso es el siguiente:

```
public function read($orden_id)
{
    $arrayTemporal = $this->ordenController->read($orden_id);
    $this->orden = $this->utf8size($arrayTemporal);
    echo json_encode($this->orden, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}

public function utf8size($d) {
    if (is_array($d)) {
        foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
            $d[$k] = $this->utf8size($v);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($d)) {
        return utf8_encode($d);
    }
    return $d;
}
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar estaré muy agradecido.
Sin mas por el momento me despido.

Comment: Revisa 3 cosas, 1.- Que tu hoja archivo donde estes haciendo el envío de datos este en formato utf8, 2.- que tengas la meta utf8, 3.- cuando consultes la Bd agrega esto: `mysqli_query($conexion,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");` si es que utilizad mysqli

Comment: Esto te puede servir de ayuda [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%C3%A1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base)

Comment: Este es un error común, revisa esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/38103 y esta otra https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134130/c%c3%b3mo-migrar-reparar-datos-insertados-con-codificaci%c3%b3n-incorrecta-en-mysql

Answer (score 0):

- Para codificar utf8 en php `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
- Para codificar utf8 en html `<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>`
- Para inserciones y consultas mysql coloca `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` donde realizas las conexion a la base de datos o bien cuando realizas la consulta o el insert
- *Recuerda tambien tener en la base de datos la codificacion utf_general_ci

Comment: a mi me llego a servir en su momento el punto 3 pero implementando PDO.

Answer (score -1):

Ahorra s usa `mysqli` y no `mysql` - yo he resuelto el problema agregando esto al archivo de conexión:

```
$enlace= mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$clave,$basededatos);
$enlace-> set_charset("utf8");
```