# utf8 decodificacion desde xml para mysql acentos

Tags: php, mysql, xml, acentos

Buen dia

tengo un xml que me entregan desde una web la cual al llamarla se ve así tal cual en pantalla:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<nombre><![CDATA[TÓNER]]></nombre>
```

tengo la palabra TÓNER con acentos ya viene del xml bien escrito pero al volcarlo ala Base de datos MYSQL el campo nombre con formato texto me aparece asi:

**TÃ“NER**

tengo este código antes de subirlo al MYSQL

```
utf8_encode(utf8_decode($tabla[nombre]))
```

no se que hacer para que el campo se suba al MYSQL con el acento.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/133598/c%C3%B3mo-admitir-tildes-php-mysql

Comment: vale pero no me genera este carácter � si no este: Ã“ para la tilde he probado el link pero no funciona

Comment: El XML dice tener codificación UTF8, entonces, no necesitas usar las funciones utf8, simplemente guarda el valor. A menos que tu base de datos o scripts usen otro juego de caracteres.

Comment: no se si el [CDATA influye en la codificación?

Comment: El problema puede deberse también al objeto conexión. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967) donde he abordado este problema en los diferentes niveles donde podría ocurrir.